# Permanently change Powershell syntax highlight colors lowered execution policy

Tags: colors, powershell-5.0

I changed the colors of Powershell but now the syntax highlights are hard to see so I figured out how to change them but they do not stay permanently. I tried putting the following command in the $PROFILE.AllUsersAllHosts file (which I had to create):

```
Set-PSReadlineOption -Colors @{
    Operator = "DarkRed"
    Comment = "DarkGreen"
    Type = "DarkMagenta"
    Member = "DarkGray"
    Number = "Blue"
    Command = "Magenta"
}
```

But when I start Powershell it says "cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system." Running "Get-ExecutionPolicy" it says Restricted, I can't imagine it's that important but I would like to change the colors without lowering the execution policy, is it possible?

Comment: No, that's not possible. Since the PowerShell profile is a script, you have to lower it to at least `RemoteSigned`. Furthermore, the execution policy isn't really helpful against malicious content, if that is your concern, because you can run powershell with the parameter `-ExecutionPolicy ByPass` to run any PowerShell script from a command line and bypass your setting. With "RemoteSigned", every script which wasn't created by you or isn't signed by a trusted publisher, will be blocked until you use `Unblock-File <scriptPath>`.